# Parse server error "Protocol not supported"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-server

I've been migrating datas for two days now, everything is ok in AWS - I used a Bitnami MEAN machine, it was only a very small app.
FYI, I'm moving from Heroku + Parse, set up also nginx on AWS to run more than one nodejs app.
I had to downgrade the default mongodb installation due to incompatibility with Parse (WHY?)

So, straight to the problem: installed node.js parse server, configured like they show on git

```
var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/database',
  cloud: './cloud/main.js',
  appId: 'my-app-id',
  masterKey: 'my-master-key'
});
```

but when I try to execute any query I got

```
Error: Protocol not supported.
   at send (/opt/bitnami/apps/bellboy-admin/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:299:15)
   at dispatch (/opt/bitnami/apps/bellboy-admin/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse/lib/node/RESTController.js:137:11)
   at Object.ajax (/opt/bitnami/apps/bellboy-admin/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse/lib/node/RESTController.js:139:5)
   at ParsePromise.<anonymous> (/opt/bitnami/apps/bellboy-admin/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse/lib/node/RESTController.js:208:29)
   at ParsePromise.wrappedResolvedCallback (/opt/bitnami/apps/bellboy-admin/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse/lib/node/ParsePromise.js:135:41)
   at /opt/bitnami/apps/bellboy-admin/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse/lib/node/ParsePromise.js:196:35
   at runLater (/opt/bitnami/apps/bellboy-admin/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse/lib/node/ParsePromise.js:180:12)
   at ParsePromise.then (/opt/bitnami/apps/bellboy-admin/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse/lib/node/ParsePromise.js:195:9)
   at Object.request (/opt/bitnami/apps/bellboy-admin/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse/lib/node/RESTController.js:201:8)
   at Object.find (/opt/bitnami/apps/bellboy-admin/node_modules/parse-server/node_modules/parse/lib/node/ParseQuery.js:1141:27)
```

I tried almost everything, any ideas from you?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the dependencies for ParseServer? More specifically, is the MondoDB NodeJS drive installed?

`npm install mongodb`

If it helps, [I have a tutorial](https://www.webniraj.com/2016/01/31/parse-com-setting-up-the-open-source-parse-api-server/) that explains how the ParseServer should be setup, providing you have MongoDB and NodeJS already installed to the correct versions.

Comment: Yeah, everything was fine, I eventually solved, editing the post.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

I guessed it was something involving the http/https protocols between my node app and parse server so I just added the http:// before the address of Parse.serverURL

```
Parse.initialize('my-id','unused');
Parse.serverURL = 'http://localhost:3030/parse';
```

Maybe it goes by default on https when not specified.